# Eclipse Juno project explorer

Tags: eclipse

Folks,

I am working on one big project and using Eclipse for the same.

I am working with the set of files (40 or so) and opening them via 'Project Explorer' view.

Now problem is project explorer is keeping 5 active files and remaining 35 are hidden (>> will show all these files)

Now when ever I open any file from list of 35 files randomly some 5 files are becoming active

e.g. I am working with file A,B,C,D,E and remaining 35 are hidden (>> symbol can expand them)

Now when I select file "X" by expanding >> symbol it is having P,Q,R,T,X as 5 active files (ideally I would like to have X,A,B,C,D)

This is becoming tedious I am using Eclipse JUNA,JUNO.

Same is visible with package explorer view.

Comment: Was there a question to go with this?

Comment: Ideally I would like to have files X,A,B,C,D open how to achieve this